# How could I run Sublime Text 2 without X server?

Tags: ssh, sublime-text-2, x11-forwarding

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and it's an awesome editor.
Sometimes I'm on a slow connection editing remote files and X11 over SSH is too damn slow to be of any use. 
I could only run Sublime on the remote machine due to special reasons. And I've already checked alternatives like NX and other remote desktop solutions.

Is it possible to use Sublime in SSH terminal without using X server at all?
Like vim, but with a human face.

If this is not possible, would it be hard for me to implement?
Looks like this could not be done via plugin.

Comment: I added this as a request for a feature: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/449834-/

Answer (score 2):

[Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) is an SFTP plugin for sublime that may help.  That would allow you to run sublime locally and edit the remote files.  It also makes it easy to mirror the remote files with a local folder if thats an acceptable solution

Comment: I also had some success with using SSHFS instead of Sublime plugins. It does not require you to have any files locally, but is very slow on any file listing operations.